# What is the strongest configuration for Stockfish?

Tags: uci

I'm using [stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/) chess engine and I want to setup strongest configuration. I'm running this commands

```
ucinewgame
setoption name threads value 2
position fen rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq -
go depth 20
```

[Here](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html) is list of uci protocol options, and I want to know how can I set strongest options? Need I use **Hash** option for example or I need just set maximum value for **depth** option